# MVC WIF and SAML Cross Domain SSO

Tags: single-sign-on, wif

Can anyone tell me how to develop Cross Domain SSO using WIF, STS and SAML?

I have site a and site b which are hosted on different servers and want to have SSO option between these 2 sites.

i want to use WIF for this.

Can anyone tell me how to achieve this ?

It will be good if someone can provide code sample.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to provide more detail.

You mention WIF and SAML - WIF doesn't support SAML so where does SAML come into the picture?

Are sites a and b in different domains?

Do they each have their own identity repository? If so, is it AD or what?

Are sites a and b .NET applications or something else?

What STS are you using?

Comment: Hi I am using identity foundation for creating federation token and adding claims into it. Both site are on different domain and servers and both are MVC sites. I am using Custom STS